# Functions.php wordpress astra

Tags: php, html, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theme

tengo una pagina web y quiero que todos los miembros registrados aparezcan en una tabla HTML para poder entrar y tener una lista de todos los miembros, tengo este código y no se si está fallando la conexión o el que. Gracias

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'dcms_list_data' );

function dcms_list_data( $content ) {
$database_name = 'name'; // nombre de la base de datos
$database_user = 'user';
$database_pass = 'pass';
$database_server = 'localhost';

$table_name = 'wp_users'; // nombre de la tabla
$slug_page = 'pruebas'; //slug de la página en donde se mostrará la tabla

if (is_page($slug_page)){

    $mydb = new wpdb($database_user, $database_pass, $database_name, 
$database_server);
    $items = $mydb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `$table_name`");

    // nombre de los campos de la tabla
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $result .= '<tr>
            <td>'.$item->user_login.'</td>
            <td>'.$item->user_email.'</td>
            <td>'.$item->display_name.'</td>
        </tr>';
    }

    $template = '<table class="table-data">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Usuario</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                  </tr>
                  {data}
                </table>';

    return $content.str_replace('{data}', $result, $template);
}

return $content;
}
```

Este es el código, parece como que aveces se me guarda en la web y otras no se me actualiza no entiendo que esta pasando. Gracias de antemano por preocuparte en mi problema

Comment: Yo te recomendaría no tocar el **Functions.php**. Deberías usar **Code Snippets** para código tuyo.

Comment: No es necesario ir a la DB para eso, puedes usar get_users() o WP_User_Query para obtener a los usuarios registrados.